# perl help replacing commas and embedding values with ctrl characters

Tags: perl

I need some help with tweaking my perl script.

I've got an input file with comma separated values like so:

```
to_em,from_em,flags,updated,marks
xtr133823@xra.co.nz#hv,abc@def.com,16,2007-08-18 16:18:50,33
```

The first row are the **column names** `to_em  from_em  flags  updated  marks` and the following record are the values for each column:

```
to_em = xtr133823@xra.co.nz#hv
from_em = abc@def.com
flags = 16
updated = 2007-08-18 16:18:50
marks = 33
```

I am also creating a unique value (MD5), prefixed with "`__pkey__`".

Each column name starts with `^E`. Each value starts with `^A`, including the hex value. The record will end with `^D`.

I want the final output file to look like this:

```
__pkey__^Ad41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e^Eto_em^Axtr133823@xra.co.nz#hv^Efrom_em^Aabc@def.com^Eflags^A16^Eupdated^A2007-08-18 16:18:50^Emarks^A33^E^D
```

But, its coming out like this:

```
__pkey__^Ad41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e^E^Ato_em^E^D__pkey__^A5c09354d0d3d34c96dbad8fa14ff175e^E^Axtr133823@xra.co.nz#hv^E^D
```

Here's my code:

```
use strict;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
my $data = '';
while (<>) {
my $digest = md5_hex($data);
   chomp;
   my ($val) = split /,/;
   $data = $data. "__pkey__^A$digest^E^A$val^E^D";
}
print $data;
exit;
```

Comment: Your code pretty much has nothing to do with what you want the result to be except the while loop and the split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
use strict;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
my $data = '';
my $line1 = <>;
chomp $line1;
my @heading = split /,/, $line1;
#my ($sep1, $sep2, $eor) = (chr(1), chr(5), chr(4));
my ($sep1, $sep2, $eor) = ( "^A", "^E", "^D");
while (<>)
{
    my $digest = md5_hex($data);
    chomp;
    my (@values) = split /,/;
    my $extra = "__pkey__$sep1$digest$sep2" ;
    $extra .= "$heading[$_]$sep1$values[$_]$sep2" for (0..$#values);
    #$extra .= "$heading[$_]$sep1$values[$_]$sep2" for (0..scalar(@values)-1);
    #for my $i (0..$#values)
    #{
    #   $extra .= "$heading[$i]$sep1$values[$i]$sep2";
    #}
    $data .= "$extra$eor";
}
print $data;
```

It reads the first line, chomps it, and splits it into fields into the array `@heading`.

It reads each subsequent line, chomps it, splits it into fields, runs the digest on it, and then generates the output line.

At the end, it prints all the accumulated data.

If you want actual control characters instead of caret-letter, use the line with `chr()` instead of the following one.

If you don't like the all-on-one-line loop, use the commented out one.

Comment: This works well! Thanks for the description and for showing me the other options as well.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you the kind of output you showed

```
use strict;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
my $data = '';

my $first_line = <>;
chomp($first_line);
my @columns = split(/,/, $first_line);
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my (@vals) = split /,/;
    my $record = "";
    foreach my $column_num (0..$#columns) {
        $record .= "^E$columns[$column_num]^A$vals[$column_num]";
    }
    my $digest = md5_hex($data);
    $data = $data. "__pkey__^A$digest$record^D";
}
print $data;
exit;
```